# Select all the data from another table even if corresponding value from another table is NULL

Tags: sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT city.CITY_NAME, 
       SUM(case when c.CUSTOMER_ID=o.CUSTOMER_ID and o.ORDER_ID=od.ORDER_ID 
                then od.TOTAL_AMT_PER_ITEM 
                else 0 end) AS TOTAL_AMT_PER_ITEM
FROM [ORDER] o
INNER JOIN ORDER_DETAILS od
   ON o.ORDER_ID = od.ORDER_ID
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER c
   ON o.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_ADDRESS ca
   ON ca.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID
INNER JOIN CITY city
   ON ca.CITY_ID = city.CITY_ID
GROUP BY city.CITY_NAME
```

I am a beginner in SQL SERVER. This query displays only the `CITY_NAME` that has a corresponding `TOTAL_AMT_PER_ITEM` value. What I need is to display all the `CITY_NAMEs` in the database even if their corresponding value is NULL. What is the work around for this? Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: You need [**LEFT JOIN**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) instead `INNER JOIN`

Comment: I just need to replace all the INNER JOINs with LEFT JOINs?

Comment: And You don't need the case statement in your SUM. You are taking care of that in your joins.

Comment: You need to spend a little time understanding joins. This is a great article on the topic. http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Not sure because you didnt provide enough data for me to guess. So I just point you to the right direction, see the link and you will get an idea of how use it. Otherwise provide sample data and expected output. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    city.CITY_NAME, 
    SUM(od.TOTAL_AMT_PER_ITEM) AS TOTAL_AMT_PER_ITEM
FROM 
    CUSTOMER c
INNER JOIN 
    CUSTOMER_ADDRESS ca
    ON ca.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID
INNER JOIN 
    CITY city
    ON ca.CITY_ID = city.CITY_ID
LEFT JOIN
    [ORDER] o
    ON o.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID
LEFT JOIN
    ORDER_DETAILS 
    ON o.ORDER_ID = od.ORDER_ID
GROUP BY city.CITY_NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

I change the order of the joins maybe that help.

- You start with `CITY` because is the source for your `GROUP BY` and try to see if have any `CUSTOMER_ADDRESS`.

  - I guess if is a new store you can have 0 customers.
- Then `INNER JOIN`  because direction cant exist alone, they belong to a customer
- Then `LEFT JOIN` because again a `CUSTOMER` may or may not have `[ORDERS]`.
- Then `INNER JOIN` because every `[ORDERS]` have `[ORDER DETAILS]`
- Finally you `SUM(od.TOTAL_AMT_PER_ITEM)` from the last `JOIN` table, this can get some `NULL's` so you need include `COALESCE`

  ```
  SELECT city.CITY_NAME, 
         COALESCE(SUM(od.TOTAL_AMT_PER_ITEM) , 0) as TOTAL_AMT_PER_ITEM
  FROM [CITY]  
  LEFT JOIN [CUSTOMER_ADDRESS] ca
         ON ca.CITY_ID = [CITY].CITY_ID
  INNER JOIN CUSTOMER c
     ON ca.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID
  LEFT JOIN [ORDER] o
     ON o.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID
  INNER JOIN ORDER_DETAILS od
     ON o.ORDER_ID = od.ORDER_ID       
  GROUP BY [CITY].CITY_NAME
  ```

btw you should change the name of the table `[Order]` to `[Orders]` because Order is a reserved word and can cause problems.

In general I rather use the plural name for tables because is an entity saving multiple of one type

- CITIES instead of CITY
- CUSTOMERS intead of CUSTOMER
- ORDER_DETAILS is already plural, so try to keep consistence.